# Problem installing imagehash package on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, pip

I want to install a python package named `imagehash`.
I tried to install with pip but I get an exception thrown:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): imagehash in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking scipy (from imagehash)
Downloading scipy-0.15.1.tar.gz (11.4MB): 4.2MB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
  requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
do_download,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
self.session,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
for chunk in resp_read(4096):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
chunk_size, decode_content=False):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 500, in read
return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 539, in readinto
n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 371, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 746, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 618, in read
v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

Storing debug log for failure in /home/yashar/.pip/pip.log
```

I want to use this module on python2 but it seems it is compiling for python 3,
I typed `sudo pip install imagehash`